# NP-completeness of bipartite planar graph problem

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, np-complete, bipartite-graphs, decision-problems

I want to know whether a certain graph problem is NP-complete or not. The problem is as follows.

> Given an undirected planar bipartite graph with in every vertex a number. Can you make a subgraph for which the degree of every vertex is equal to the corresponding number?

Does anyone have an idea whether this problem is NP-complete, or know a related problem?

Comment: Can't you solve it by using max flow?

Comment: That is a good remark, I think we actually can.